# How can i plot my data?

Tags: matlab, plot

```
field_names = {'A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};
Values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

I want to plot that, what i tried:

```
figure
bar(values(field_names))
xlabel('field_names')
ylabel('values')
```

but i get this error:

Error using subsindex

```
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for
values of class 'cell'.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to index `values` with `field_names`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
c = categorical({'A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H'});
Values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

figure
bar(c,Values)
xlabel('field_names')
ylabel('values')
```

Comment: This link can be helpful https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html

Comment: try using this c = categorical({'A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H'});
then bar(c, values).

Comment: I don't see names just numbers in the X axis

Comment: @Steve have you tried this code : 
c = categorical({'A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H'});
Values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

figure
bar(c,Values)
xlabel('field_names')
ylabel('values')

Because it is working fine on my side

Comment: got this error Warning: Using only the real component of
complex data.  my data isn't exactly 1,2,3,4,5 it's doubles mostly |10e-2| range

Answer (score 0):

The plot does not work because field_names is a character cell and bar function does not allow it.
You need to change field_names to 'categorical' using categorical(field_names) like so:

```
figure
bar(Values,categorical(field_names))
xlabel('field_names')
ylabel('values')
```

Or this:

```
figure
bar(Values)
set(gca,'xticklabel',field_names)
xlabel('field_names')
ylabel('values')
```

Comment: Doesn't work i get numbers in the x axis it's the same approach the other answer suggested.

Comment: Try this:
bar(Values)
set(gca,'xticklabel',field_names)
xlabel('field_names')
ylabel('values')